# XCode crashes everytime my app in the iOS simulator crashes

Tags: xcode, debugging, crash, simulator

When an app in the simulator crashes, and XCode goes into debug mode (execution pauses as an exception break point), XCode self destructs and closes. It also appears to happen with break points in general, not just exception break points.

I've tried re-installing XCode, and resetting the simulator, and can't get this behavior to stop. It didn't happen until I upgraded to the 2015 version of the Retina Macbook Pro. I'm running OSX Yosemite 10.10.2, with XCode 6.2.

Cleaning the project also doesn't work.

Comment: This post is more of a problem report than a question.  If you want help, please provide specific information such as the crash log itself.

Comment: I get the same problem, any fixes?